# Subfigure caption appear always Uppercase

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

I'm using a template from overleaf and the subfigure caption appear always Uppercase.

I've tried `\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}` and also `\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{\roman{subfigure}}` but nothing changes, still appearing uppercase.

Any idea what can be affecting this? I've looked for subfigure, caption, Alph, but I've not found anything.

Thank you.

Comment: welcome to the site! how are `caption` and `subcaption` defined? without to see small complete document, which demonstrate your problem, is difficult to say anything.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, probably, but we don't know, which document class OP use, how is caption defined ... we really need MWE.